# how do you use the indices in a numpy array for calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I want the perimeterpoints function to work, but I am not sure how to run through the indices of my array. I thought len of my array would work, but it said 'in' object is not iterable. So if I had 10 points that would produce indices of 0 to 9.

```
import math as m
import numpy as np
def ball(numpoints):
    rr = 5. #radius of the ball
    xx = np.linspace(-5,5,numpoints) #x coordinates
    yy = np.array([m.sqrt(rr**2 - xxi**2) for xxi in xx]) #y coordinates
    perimeterpoints = np.array([m.sqrt((xx[i+1]-xx[i])**2+(yy[i+1]-yy[i])**2) for i in range(len(xx)-1)])
    perimeter = sum(perimeterpoints)
    return(perimeter)
```

thanks in advance

edit

I think I got it. I put range() around len(xx)-1 which i fixed in my code above. I got the right answer

Comment: perimpoints = np.hypot(diff(xx),diff(yy))...I don't think either list comprehension is necessary if you make better use of numpy.

Comment: okay cool, but can i use numpy to calculate the area of each segment?

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy` you don't need to iterate explicitly.  You can use indexing ranges, e.g. `xx[1:]` corresponds to indexing with `i+1`.  `xx[:-1]`, all but last.

```
def ball(numpts):
    rr = 5
    xx = np.linspace(-5,5,numpts)
    yy = np.sqrt(rr**2-xx**2)
    perimeterpoints = np.sqrt((xx[1:]-xx[:-1])**2+(yy[1:]-yy[:-1])**2)
    perimeter = np.sum(perimeterpoints)
    return perimeter
```

Comment: Whenever you see something like `yy[1:]-yy[:-1]` in NumPy, you may use `np.diff(yy)` instead...

Comment: `np.diff` ends up doing the same thing.  It's a nice shortcut, but writing your own slices is an important starting point.